# Why can't we initialize a 2D integer array as a pointer?

Tags: c

Why can a 2D character array be initialized as a pointer but not as a 2D integer array?  Why does it give an error when I try to do so?  Also, what does initializing an array as a pointer mean?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char* m[] = { "Excellent","Good", "bad" };
    int* x[] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6} }; 
    return 0;                      
}
```

Comment: Because it's not a pointer; they are laid out contiguously. `{}` does not mean a pointer always. You could actually leave out the inner brackets entirely after, of course, you've written a proper 2d type decl though it might cause compiler warnings.

Comment: `{1,2,3}` and `{4,5,6}` are not of type `int*`. And where did you read the phrase "initializing an array as a pointer"? `char *m[]` is an array of character pointers.

Comment: So "Excellent" and "good" are of type int* ? If yes, how?

Comment: No, they are pointers, as you declared, `char *`.

Comment: The difference is that a string literal can be used where a `char *` is needed, but an array initializer like `{1,2,3}` cannot be used where an `int *` is needed.

Comment: So, why aren't the integers 1,2,3 of type int*, I have also declared them as int*

Comment: Why is it that so? @user3386109

Comment: It's a quirk of the language. A string literal can be used to initialize an array of characters, or can be used to initialize a single `char *`. That's just the way it is.

Comment: BTW, that code snippet does not have any 2D arrays. `m` is a 1D array of `char` pointers. `x` is a 1D array of `int` pointers. The initializer for `m` is an array of `char` pointers (and hence matches the declaration of `m`). But the initializer for `x` is an array of array of `int`. The initializer for `x` is **not** an array of `int` pointers (which is needed to match the declaration of `x`).

Comment: I do not want to say something wrong, but I think because literal strings has Adressen and all others constants (char, int, float) they do not have. This is what works with char*

Comment: @Michi What is Adressen?

Comment: @MMH My phone makes jokes :) . I mean they have memory addresses. And constants like return &(5) they do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of a declaration, `{` and `}` just mean “here is a group of things.” They do not represent an object or an address or an array. (Note: Within initializations, there are expressions, and those expressions can contain braces in certain contexts that do represent objects. But, in the code shown in the question, the braces just group things.)

In `char* m[] = { "Excellent","Good", "bad" };`, three items are listed to initialize `m`: `"Excellent"`, `"Good"`, and `"bad"`. So each item initializes one element of `m`.

`"Excellent"` is a string literal. During compilation, it becomes an array of characters, terminated by a null character. In some situations, an array is kept as an array:

- When it is used as the operand of `sizeof`.
- When it is used as the operand of unary `&` (for taking an address).
- When it is a string literal used to initialize an array.

None of these apply in this situation. `"Excellent"` is not the operand of `sizeof`, it is not the operand of `&`, and it is initializing just one element of `m`, not the entire array. So, the array is not kept as an array: By a rule in C, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Then this pointer initializes `m[0]`: `m[0]` is a pointer to the first element of `"Excellent"`.

Similarly, `m[1]` is initialized to a pointer to the first element of `"Good"`, and `m[2]` is initialized to a pointer to the first element of `"bad"`.

In `int* x[] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6} };`, two things are listed to initialize `x`. Each of these things is itself a group (of three things). However, `x` is an array of `int *`. Each member of `x` should be initialized with a pointer. But a group of three things, `{1,2,3}`, is not a pointer.

The C rules on interpreting groups of things when initializing arrays and structures are a bit complicated, because they are designed to provide some flexibility for omitting braces, so I have to study the standard a bit more to explain how they apply here. Suffice it to say that the compiler interprets the declaration as using `1` to initialize `x[0]`. Since `1` is an `int` and `x[0]` is an `int *`, the compiler complains that the types do not match.

## Supplementary Notes

`char *m[]` does not declare a two-dimensional array. It is an array of pointers to `char`. Because of C’s rules, it can generally be used syntactically the same way as a two-dimensional array, so that `m[i][j]` picks out character `j` of string `i`. However, there is a difference between `char *m[]` and `char a[3][4]`, for example:

- In `m[i][j]`, `m[i]` is a pointer. That pointer is loaded from memory and use as the base address for `[j]`. Then `j` is added to that address, and the character there is loaded from memory. **There are two memory loads in this evaluation.**
- In `a[i][j]`, `a[i]` is an array. The location of this array is calculated by arithmetic from the start of `a`. Then `a[i][j]` is a `char`, and its address is calculated by adding `j`, and the character there is loaded from memory. **There is one memory load in this evaluation.**

There is a syntax for initialization an array of `int` pointers to point to an array of `int`. It is called a *compound literal*. This is infrequently used:

```
int *x[] = { (int []) {1, 2, 3}, (int []) {4, 5, 6} };
```

A crucial difference between these string literals and compound literals is that string literals define objects which exist for the lifetime of program execution, but compound literals used inside functions have an automatic storage duration—it will vanish when your function returns, and possibly earlier, depending on where it is used. Novice C programmers should avoid using compound literals until they understand the storage duration rules.

Comment: ... please add a note that these are no 2D arrays

Comment: *"In some situations, an array is kept as an array: When it is used to initialize an array."* this would mean that you can use an array to initialize another array, which is not a case and only applies to using a string literal. An array identifier does decay to a pointer in an initializer context, which will result in an invalid initializer.

Comment: “During compilation, it becomes an array of characters, terminated by a null character.” Can you please provide an explanation with some resources, where the standard says that it happens like that? I mean “char *ptr = “hello” is Ok, because the literal string has an Adresse and the pointer ptr points to it. int *ptr = 5; is wrong because 5 it is a constant integer and as far as i know in C, constant integers has no addresses hence the reason why int *ptr = 5; does not work. I would like to see some reference about that statement please. Thank you.

Comment: I think I found something in Standard C section 6.4.5, paragraph 6: In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence. I am not sure if that is what you meant.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: There is a big **<h1>** headline with a note that `char *m[]` is not a two-dimensional array and explaining the difference. Did you want more?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I updated the list of automatic conversion exceptions to distinguish string literals used to initialize arrays.

Comment: @Michi: Yes, that passage in the C standard is what I was alluding to.